# How to know the elapsed time for json date

Tags: android, json, date, time, elapsedtime

I have a list of item which gets its data from server via json link, and one of the attribute is the date/time in which the item was created like so:

```
created_at: "2017-05-13T08:53:40Z"
```

I want to show this time in textview on top of each item but in Facebook-status like format =>

**1 minute ago | 2 hours ago | 4 days ago | 5 months ago etc..**

how can I do that.!?

**Update**

here's my my latest attempt. '_'

```
  public String getOrderTime() {

    GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
    Date time = getTime(); // getTime is coming from json

    Log.i("Json Time ", time + "");

    long MILLIS_PER_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    long timePortion = time.getTime() % MILLIS_PER_DAY;

    Log.i("New Json Time ", timePortion + "");
    Log.i("Time Now ", now.getTimeInMillis() + "");

    String elapsed_time = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
            timePortion,
            now.getTimeInMillis(),
            DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS)
            .toString();

    Log.i("Elapsed Time", elapsed_time);

    return elapsed_time;
 }
```

**Here are the logs, clearly something is wrong**

```
I/Json Time: Sun May 14 03:27:22 EDT 2017
I/New Json Time: 26842000
I/Time Now: 1494747376756
I/Elapsed Time: Jan 1, 1970
```

---

**Update 2**

The new Method

```
  public String getOrderTime() {

    long end_time = theTime().getTime();  // json time
    long right_now = System.currentTimeMillis(); // right now

    Log.i("Time Now ", right_now + "");
    Log.i("Json Time ", end_time + "");

    long difference = right_now - end_time;
    Log.i("Elapsed Time", difference + "");

    if (difference < 60) {

        Log.i("Time in Minutes", difference + "m");
        return  difference + "m";

    } else {
        difference /= 60;
        if (difference < 24) {

            Log.i("Time in Hours", difference + "h");
            return difference + "h";

        } else {
            difference /= 30;

            Log.i("Time in Months", difference + "mo");
            return difference + "mo";
        }
    }
```

**The Logs**

```
     I/Time Now: 1494762022853
     I/Json Time: 1494758529000
     I/Elapsed Time: 3493853
     I/Time in Months: 1941mo
```

Comment: Parse the date and compare it to the current date. At which point do you have difficulties?

Comment: @Henry check the update

Comment: The first problem is to compare just the time portion of one timestamp with the full second timestamp.

Comment: is there a chance you could show how to solve this, i really could use ur help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to calculate the `difference` between two dates, namely your given date and the current date:

```
long difference = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()
```

`difference` will hold the difference in milliseconds

```
difference /= 60000; //minutes

if (difference < 60) {
    //minutes
} else {
    difference /= 60; //hours
    if (difference < 24) {
        //hours
    } else {
        difference /= 24; //days
        if (difference < 30) {
            //days
        } else {
            //months
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to show it in a format that make sense..!? please check **Update 2**

Comment: @SamZar you left out this line `difference /= 60000;`

Comment: @SamZar, Henry is right. You are working with milliseconds in your update instead of seconds.

Comment: oh, my bad.. I think it's showing result that make a lot more sense, thank you a lot man, but what if I wanna show `days` before `months`, what condition would that be..?

Comment: @SamZar yes, you are right, please check out my edit.